# How to remove typed characters on confirm password after removing characters on password?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can I remove typed characters on confirm password field after removing characters on password field? When you put some characters on password field you will able to put some characters on confirm password field but when you clear the characters on password field the characters on confirm password remain and disabled the field.

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            <div class="input-container">
                <label for="Password">* Password</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-container">
                <input name="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.Password" pInputText required/>
                <br>
                <label for="Password" style="font-size: 15px"><i>At least 8 characters and must be a combination of letters and numbers.</i></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-container">
                <label for="Confirm Password">* Confirm Password</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 ">
            <div class="input-container">
                <input name="confirmpass" id="Confirm Password" [disabled]="!SignUp.Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.ConfirmPassword" pInputText required/>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsDYI.png][1]

Comment: set ``SignUp.ConfirmPassword =""``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like `(ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)"` which will help you monitor change in the model value.

```
<div class="col-12">
          <div class="row mb-3">
              <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <label for="Password">* Password</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <input name="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.Password" pInputText required (ngModelChange)="SignUp.ConfirmPassword = null "/>
                      <br>
                      <label for="Password" style="font-size: 15px"><i>At least 8 characters and must be a combination of letters and numbers.</i></label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <label for="Confirm Password">* Confirm Password</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <input name="confirmpass" id="Confirm Password" [disabled]="!SignUp.Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.ConfirmPassword" pInputText required/>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the template you could use this:

```
<div class="col-12">
          <div class="row mb-3">
              <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <label for="Password">* Password</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <input name="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.Password" (ngModelChange)="SignUp.ConfirmPassword=$event ? SignUp.ConfirmPassword :''" pInputText required (ngModelChange)="SignUp.ConfirmPassword = null "/>
                      <br>
                      <label for="Password" style="font-size: 15px"><i>At least 8 characters and must be a combination of letters and numbers.</i></label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <label for="Confirm Password">* Confirm Password</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                  <div class="input-container">
                      <input name="confirmpass" id="Confirm Password" [disabled]="!SignUp.Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.ConfirmPassword" pInputText required/>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```